# Sccs файлы на хостинге

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, gulp, scss

Учусь вёрстке, и увидел в панели разработчика на одном сайте что стили ссылаются на файл Sccs, который лежит на сервере. 
[image: Картинка]

Я был увеерн что браузер понимает только css файлы. А scss надо компилировать. Покажите что почитать или обьясните как так то))))

Comment: Всё правильно, браузер понимает только css. Вероятно используются source map. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21504707  https://medium.com/@toolmantim/getting-started-with-css-sourcemaps-and-in-browser-sass-editing-b4daab987fb0